# Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] when trying to access nested JSON data

Tags: json, angularjs

I have an angular app that makes a `$http` get call to a php script, which echoes an JSON object. I previously had my JSON data written directly inside the controller, but then I had to add some validation before displaying it, so I made this php script.

I used [this tool](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) in order to check if my JSON data was valid. I can see the data with firebug (and in my console, since I `console.log` it), and it seems fine to me, but for some reason I get the following error message : `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: stran in vsebina, Duplicate key: string: , Duplicate value:`.

I have no idea what's going on.

Here's my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ZICApp')
    .controller('FotokopirnicaController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.vsebina = [];

        $http.get('http://localhost/ZIC/ip%20test/fotokopirnica.php').
            success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.vsebina = data;
            }).
             error(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    });
```

my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="stran in vsebina">

    <div class="panel-content">
        <div>
            <p class="center">{{ stran.greeting }}</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="fotokopirnica-title">{{ stran.title }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="row " ng-repeat="panel in stran.panels">

            <div class="col-xs-8 subheading fotokopirnica-content"><p>{{ panel.title }}</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.row1"><p>{{ panel.row1 }}</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.row2"><p>{{ panel.row2 }}</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.singleRow"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.singleRow"><p>&nbsp;{{ panel.singleRow }}</p></div>

            <div ng-repeat="row in panel.content">
                <div class="col-xs-8">{{ row.item }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 cena">{{ row.row1 }}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 cena">{{ row.row2 }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

the GET request response:

```
{
   "greeting":"Za potrebe sodelavcev IJS tiskamo, fotokopiramo, skeniramo in vežemo dokumente.",
   "title":"IJS cenik fotokopiranja",
   "panels":[
      {
         "title":"ČB fotokopiranje",
         "row1":"A4",
         "row2":"A3",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija",
               "row1":"0,06 €",
               "row2":"0,09 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija na barvni papir",
               "row1":"0,10 €",
               "row2":"0,15 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija vezanega gradiva",
               "row1":"0,07 €",
               "row2":"0,10 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija na prosojnico",
               "row1":"0,65 €",
               "row2":"/"
            },
            {
               "item":"Skeniranje",
               "row1":"0,10 €",
               "row2":"0,10 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
        "title":"Barvno fotokopiranje",
        "row1":"A4",
        "row2":"A3",
        "content":[
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija 80g papir",
               "row1":"0,60 €",
               "row2":"0,90 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija vezanega gradiva 80g papir",
               "row1":"0,70 €",
               "row2":"1,00 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija 100g papir",
               "row1":"1,00 €",
               "row2":"1,50 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija na prosojnico",
               "row1":"1,40 €",
               "row2":"/"
            },
            {
               "item":"Skeniranje",
               "row1":"0,10 €",
               "row2":"0,10 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"Vezave",
         "singleRow":" ",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"Termo vezava do 50 listov",
               "row2":"1,13 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Termo vezava nad 50 listov",
               "row2":"1,46 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Vezava A",
               "row2":"1,25 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Vezava B",
               "row2":"1,46 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Vezava C",
               "row2":"1,90 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Ovitek",
               "row2":"0,42 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"Ostale Storitve",
         "singleRow":"ura",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"Zgibanje na stroju",
               "row2":"23,48 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Ročno delo",
               "row2":"21,39 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"Količinski popusti",
         "singleRow":" ",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"ČB fotokopija, 500-1000",
               "row2":"15%"
            },
            {
               "item":"ČB fotokopija, nad 1000",
               "row2":"33%"
            },
            {
               "item":"Barvna fotokopija, 80g papir, 25-50",
               "row2":"25%"
            },
            {
               "item":"Barvna fotokopija 80g papir, nad 50",
               "row2":"40%"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, there was an extra bracket at the end of my data `]`, that was causing trouble. Now that  I removed it, my data is parsed correctly and I just have to adjust my view accordingly.

So the data string now looks like this:

```
{
   "greeting":"Za potrebe sodelavcev IJS tiskamo, fotokopiramo, skeniramo in vežemo dokumente.",
   "title":"IJS cenik fotokopiranja",
   "panels":[
      {
         "title":"ČB fotokopiranje",
         "row1":"A4",
         "row2":"A3",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija",
               "row1":"0,06 €",
               "row2":"0,09 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija na barvni papir",
               "row1":"0,10 €",
               "row2":"0,15 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija vezanega gradiva",
               "row1":"0,07 €",
               "row2":"0,10 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija na prosojnico",
               "row1":"0,65 €",
               "row2":"/"
            },
            {
               "item":"Skeniranje",
               "row1":"0,10 €",
               "row2":"0,10 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
        "title":"Barvno fotokopiranje",
        "row1":"A4",
        "row2":"A3",
        "content":[
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija 80g papir",
               "row1":"0,60 €",
               "row2":"0,90 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija vezanega gradiva 80g papir",
               "row1":"0,70 €",
               "row2":"1,00 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija 100g papir",
               "row1":"1,00 €",
               "row2":"1,50 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Fotokopija na prosojnico",
               "row1":"1,40 €",
               "row2":"/"
            },
            {
               "item":"Skeniranje",
               "row1":"0,10 €",
               "row2":"0,10 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"Vezave",
         "singleRow":" ",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"Termo vezava do 50 listov",
               "row2":"1,13 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Termo vezava nad 50 listov",
               "row2":"1,46 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Vezava A",
               "row2":"1,25 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Vezava B",
               "row2":"1,46 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Vezava C",
               "row2":"1,90 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Ovitek",
               "row2":"0,42 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"Ostale Storitve",
         "singleRow":"ura",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"Zgibanje na stroju",
               "row2":"23,48 €"
            },
            {
               "item":"Ročno delo",
               "row2":"21,39 €"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "title":"Količinski popusti",
         "singleRow":" ",
         "content":[
            {
               "item":"ČB fotokopija, 500-1000",
               "row2":"15%"
            },
            {
               "item":"ČB fotokopija, nad 1000",
               "row2":"33%"
            },
            {
               "item":"Barvna fotokopija, 80g papir, 25-50",
               "row2":"25%"
            },
            {
               "item":"Barvna fotokopija 80g papir, nad 50",
               "row2":"40%"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and my view looks like this:

```
<div class="panel-content">
    <div>
        <p class="center">{{ vsebina.greeting }}</p>
        <br ng-show="vsebina.title">
        <br ng-show="vsebina.title">
        <p class="fotokopirnica-title" ng-show="vsebina.title">{{ vsebina.title }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-content" ng-show="vsebina.panels">
    <div class="row " ng-repeat="panel in vsebina.panels">

        <div class="col-xs-8 subheading fotokopirnica-content"><p>{{ panel.title }}</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.row1"><p>{{ panel.row1 }}</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.row2"><p>{{ panel.row2 }}</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.singleRow"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 cena subheading fotokopirnica-content" ng-show="panel.singleRow"><p>&nbsp;{{ panel.singleRow }}</p></div>

        <div ng-repeat="row in panel.content">
            <div class="col-xs-8">{{ row.item }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 cena">{{ row.row1 }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 cena">{{ row.row2 }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [track by index](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) like this:

```
ng-repeat="panel in stran.panels track by $index"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution will be to wrap your JSON data in array []

Comment: I thought I was allready doing this by declaring `$scope.vsebina = [];`, and then assigning the data to it (see the controller)

Comment: your json code starts with `{` and ends with `]` which one is correct ?

Comment: it's correct without the square bracket, should end with a curly brace `}`

Comment: cool. so as per my answer you should do [ {your current json data} ].
Just add square brackets around. The reason is you are iterating over an object and ng-repeat needs an index.